# Not able to retrieve data in the other controller using common shared service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, devextreme

I'm creating a shared service called Popup Service so that I can share data between two Controllers i.e BankController and CreateBankController.

I'm able to set the object that I need to share in the PopupService. The popupService is called within BankController (while clicking the Edit link on a data row) to set the object to be shared.

The CreateBankController is then invoked by the popup form, but in the CreateBankcontroller I'm not able to access the shared data from the PopupService, I get an error that objectToEdit variable is not defined.

1. Please can you advise how I can make the PopupService share data between the two controllers
2. Can the data in the Popup shared service end up over being overridden by competing user actions and show stale data

**WORKING PLUNKER 
https://plnkr.co/edit/y8dZNU?p=preview**

**Retrieving data in CreateBankController**

```
CreateBankController.$inject = ['PopupService'];

function CreateBankController(PopupService) {
var vm = this;

var data = {
  bankName: "",
  bankAddress: "",
};

 debugger;

if (PopupService.getObjectToEdit() !== null) {
  data = PopupService.getObjectToEdit();
}
```

**SETTING THE SHARED DATA IN THE BankController**

```
  $scope.bankGrid = {
  dataSource: queryResult,
  columns: [{
    dataField: 'orderID',
    caption: 'Order ID'
  }, {
    width: 50,
    alignment: 'center',
    caption: 'Edit',
    cellTemplate: function(container, options) {
      $('<a/>').addClass('dx-link')
        .text('Edit')
        .on('dxclick', function() {
            PopupService.addObjecToEdit(options.data);
              $scope.showPopup = true;
        })
        .appendTo(container);
    }
```

**shared data service - POPUP SERVICE**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('PopupService', PopupService);

function PopupService() {
    var popupInstance = {};
    var objectToEdit = {};

    var service = {
        addObjecToEdit : addObjecToEdit,
        getObjectToEdit: getObjectToEdit,
        showPopup: showPopup,
        hidePopup: hidePopup

    };
    return service;

    //Functions
    function addObjecToEdit(pObjectToEdit){
        objectToEdit = pObjectToEdit;
    }

    function getObjectToEdit() {
        return objecTtoEdit;
    }

    function showPopup(){
        popupInstance.showPopup();
    }

    function hidePopup(){
        popupInstance.hidePopup();
    }
}
}());
```

Comment: Are you sure `addObjecToEdit` is called before `getObjectToEdit`?

Comment: Yes, I set a break point to track the flow, I did see addObjectToEdit get called before getObjectToEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the service:

```
function getObjectToEdit() {
        return objecTtoEdit;
}
```

change to:

```
function getObjectToEdit() {
        return objectToEdit;
}
```

Comment: Ah, That's a shame I could not catch the typo, totally missed it.